# Passar Array como parâmetro para função

Tags: c, array, funções, ponteiro, parâmetros

Fazer um programa em C que leia um valor x, crie dinamicamente um vetor de x elementos e passe esse vetor para uma função que vai ler os elementos desse vetor. Depois, no programa principal, o vetor preenchido deve ser impresso. Além disso, antes de finalizar o programa, deve- se liberar a área de memória alocada.
Segue o que eu fiz e o que se pede no exercício mas eu não consegui encaixar a parte de função. Feito em DEV C ++ version 5.11.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
int i,n;
printf ("Digite o numero de elementos que deseja \n ");
scanf ("%i",&n);
int *ptr;
    ptr =(int*) malloc (n * sizeof(int));
        int i; 
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)  /*queria passar essa parte do codigo para uma funçao ... essa parte do codigo faz a leitura dos valores do vetor
    {
        printf ("Digite os valores do vetor\n");
        scanf("%d",&ptr[i]);
    }   */
        for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        printf ("%d",ptr[i]);
        }   
    free(ptr);
system("pause>null");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: E qual é o seu problema?

Comment: eu gostaria de passar ptr, n para a função para fazer a leitura de elementos do meu vetor e depois na main eu gostaria de ler os valores que foram digitados na função

Comment: Selecione o código todo e clique em `{}` para formatar tudo.

Comment: muito obrigado diego, sou novato por aqui

Comment: Vou tentar mais uma vez. Qual é o problema do código?

Comment: vou deixar o codigo funcionando e exibir a parte que gostaria de passar para a função

Comment: bigown, o problema e que eu nao consigo passar corretamente os parametro para a função e nao consigo fazer com a main leia os valores inseridos na função , por que eu nao soube declara direito, tenho essa dificuldade com função .

Comment: o teu codigo está um pouco confuso bem como a pergunta, sugiro que caso tenhas um enunciado coloques na pergunta, para que possamos ver o que é pedido e comparar com o que fizes-te para ver o que falta.
Aconselho-te também, a sempre que possas tenta indentar o código, para que seja mais fácil poderes ver o que se está a passar, ajuda na leitura visual do código.

Comment: soeiro desculpe postei as pressas e nao me preocupei com quem leria o codigo, desculpe eu entrei em outros topicos e vi que realmente dificulta muito quando o codigo esta bagunçado, eu vou melhorar nos proximos post e pensarei mais nas pessoas que estao tentando ajudar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É só passar o *array* (ponteiro) e o número de elementos para a função:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void func(int *ptr, int x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        printf("Digite o valor %d do vetor\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &ptr[i]);
    }
}
int main () {
    int x;
    printf("Digite o numero de elementos que deseja\n");
    scanf("%i", &x);
    int *ptr = malloc(x * sizeof(int));
    func(ptr, x);
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        printf ("%d\n", ptr[i]);
    }   
    free(ptr);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/SJkRQJ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gvxfnpdh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/ArrayParam2.c).

Código organizado, coerente, sem redundâncias, é mais fácil de ler?

Comment: nuss tem como eu dar algum like no seu comentario ou algo assim, fico muito bom

Comment: @ALFAEX tal como podes ver este código já está indentado, assim torna-se mais facil a leitura por ti e também por toda agente que te queira ajudar.

Comment: O que você pode fazer é aceitar, como já fez e quando tiver 15 pontos poderá votar em qualquer coisa no site. Veja o [tour].

Comment: eu vou melhorar e realmente bigown me deu um bom exemplo de como agir. Muito obrigado aprendi muito com esse post